# Do we have Tasks in Google Calendar? If not then how it is managed during migration from Outlook to Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to make Task in Google Calendar using Google Calendar API : c#.
Before that i manually tried to create Task in Google Calendar.But i didn't found it there.

So, My question is that if Task doesn't exist in Google then how Google Tool For Calendar migration manage it?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks exist in Google Calendar.

1. Look at the link below "Quick add" at your left.
2. See the long blue section below the dates display but above the calendar field where you place your events? Click there. You will get an invitation to create either an event, or a task. If you choose task, it will appear right in that blue panel.